# pay period id grouping byweekely

Tags: sql, datetime

How can I make sql to recognise my pay periods? I have table that contains list of pay period id, 26 per year. Last pay period of 2012 is 201226, first pay period of 2013 is 201301, is there a way for me to make sql calculate 201226+1=201301, 201226+2 = 201302?

Comment: You're going to want something called a 'Calendar Table' - there's a few questions on this site detailing their creation (look around).  Otherwise, you'll need to define a custom type of some sort, which is database-dependent; what RDBMS do you have?

Comment: Before I posted the question, I already looked around. Whould you please explain a bit more regarding custom type of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to keep your current design, you can simply add another field which is an incremental sequence number. Using combination of sequence number and current fields you can reach the next or previous pay period

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I use this table for several reports and use windowing function to calculate moving avg and now I have it without adding more code to the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.  I included 2 extra field `Year` and `Period` in case you ever had a need for them:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    PayPeriodId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PayPeriodId) RN,
    Left(PayPeriodId, 4) as Year, 
    Right(PayPeriodId, 2) as Period 
  FROM PayPeriods
  ) 
SELECT NextPeriod.PayPeriodId
FROM CTE CurrentPeriod
  JOIN CTE NextPeriod ON CurrentPeriod.RN + 1 = NextPeriod.RN
WHERE CurrentPeriod.PayPeriodId = '201226'
```

And here is some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21e6d/1).